# DateTime or TimeSpan Data mask?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, time, format

I am looking for a completely customized `DateTime` property data mask for the `TimeSpan` part of the `DateTime`. Or if it makes things easier I can make the property itself a `TimeSpan`

1. I need to display in 24 hour time without the seconds like these examples: `8:45` , `17:36`
2. I need the input data to be like these examples: `845 == 8:45`, `1736 == 17:36`
   Ie, the user does not have to enter the semicolon `:`

I know you can format time into a `string` like this,
`string time = new TimeSpan(8, 45, 0).ToString("HH:mm")`
But it can't be a string.
I have looked at the Docs and I can't put the this together myself. If someone could point me in the right direction as to what the mask needs to be that would be great.

EDIT: It is in WinForms

Cheers

Comment: A `TimeSpan` is a perfectly good representation of a time of day (it's the time span since midnight). Consider taking the string, checking if there's a colon (`:`), if so, `string.Split` on it. If not, get the string length and play `Substring` games, making sure that the second part is always 2 characters long

Comment: @Flydog57, the issue is I can't work with strings, I need the `TimeSpan` as the property type.

Comment: SInce this is a question about representatiopn and parsing in the UI (if I understand correctly), it would be useful to know the UI framework you use. E.g. with WPF, you could use a converter to do the translation work.

Comment: @KlausGütter, I am using `DevExpress` XAF in the WinForms application.

Comment: For input and output, you need to have a conversion from/to string, since the GUI can only show these. When it displays a time, it always converts that to a string first, because a `TimeSpan` internally uses a binary representation of time (actually a 64 bit integer). This value is useless for the user.

Comment: @PMF, My fears have been confirmed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, you'll need to create some conversion methods yourself. This code might help.

```
// Display current time
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm").TrimStart('0'));

// Read some input
var str = Console.ReadLine();

// Validate input (if required)
int time;
if (!int.TryParse(str, out time) || time < 100 || time > 2359)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid time");
    return;
}

int h = time / 100;
int m = time % 100;

if (m > 59)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid time");
    return;
}

// Construct TimeSpan and DateTime
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(h, m, 0);   // You have the TimeSpan here

var dateTime = DateTime.Now.Date + timeSpan;    // You have the DateTime here

Console.WriteLine(timeSpan);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```